# FBLikeControl does not load nor function

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

With the new release of facebook ios sdk, the documentation is talking about the facebook like control, that allows to like a page.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button/

the documentation of the control is here 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBLikeControl

Yet i tried it and it's not appearing, though i can detect a clear color rectangle only, i change the background color, the color appears on that rectangle, but not the facebook style as mentioned in the documentation.
Additionally it doesn't work, it should take me to the fb app to show the object linked to it.

I tried through an app, while configuring the project as mentioned, AppID ... and everything. I tried also from a sample project "SessionLoginSample" that comes with facebook SDK, to no avail.

The button being clear color, seems like intentional, or something broken. 
It's new so I thought that there might be problems, or, i'm doing something wrong :)

Anybody?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use FBlikeControl button by enabling below feature in viewdidload or where you create FBlikeControl button:

```
[FBSettings enableBetaFeature:FBBetaFeaturesLikeButton];
[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility:NO];
```

Comment: I have tried on view and in table but it will work every where in IOS . Please give me little detail that wt you mean by 'page' so i will check it and let you know.

Comment: The button is showing and retrieving the number of likes that page has.
But when i press on it, though i logged in using a user, through different fb app. liking a page didn't work
for example, i tried with the following objectID:
http://www.facebook.com/Trouvezlintrus.lb
269385909831446
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Pawel-Kuczynski/222849284410325

the like button does not let the page be liked

Comment: If the user have role in developer , tester or administrator then it would work without any issue but if the user are not in all these role for your app then you need to submit your app for review by fb for 2 things 1.like action and 2. publish action. when you get the public permission for both action then any user can like any link or page or any object id

Answer (score 5):

You can not change the size of button because its standard button provided by fb but you can use button style using below code:

Here is the complete code:

```
[FBSettings enableBetaFeature:FBBetaFeaturesLikeButton];
[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility:NO];
FBLikeControl *like = [[FBLikeControl alloc] init];
like.objectID = @"http://shareitexampleapp.parseapp.com/photo1/";
like.likeControlHorizontalAlignment=FBLikeControlHorizontalAlignmentRight;
like.likeControlStyle=FBLikeControlStyleBoxCount;
[self.view addSubview like];
```

Comment: any Open Graph object and can be referenced by URL or ID

Answer (score 2):

Mawoon answered worked for me. Thank you sir.

Usage example:

```
[FBSettings enableBetaFeature:FBBetaFeaturesLikeButton];
[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility:NO];

FBLikeControl *like = [[FBLikeControl alloc] init];
like.frame = CGRectMake(itemX, itemY, 60, 20);
like.likeControlStyle = FBLikeControlStyleButton;
like.objectID = @"http://shareitexampleapp.parseapp.com/photo1/";
```

For some reason I'm not being able to set the 'size' of the like button, also changing the value of the likeControlStyle is not yielding any results, could be because its still a preview feature.

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button/) its currently only preview feature, please check screenshot. My best guess is you may not have enabled developers in Facebook applications you created through app page.

[image]

Comment: thank you but i tried with an administrator role>developer>tester. and i tried through fb sample app, as updated in my question. The button should not be a clear rectangle no matter what.
But that's for your hint. If you tried it and worked for you please tell us.