# FBLikeControl : Invisible

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

I all,

I am trying to use the FBLikeControl inside my iOS App.
This control is included in the latest version of FB SDK for iOS.
No problem at build time nor exception at runtime when I include the following code (which is almost the default code proposed in the FB documentation) :

```
FBLikeControl *likeControl = [[FBLikeControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 76, 69, 28)];
[likeControl setObjectID:@"http://samples.ogp.me/276797645833250"];
[likeControl setLikeControlStyle:FBLikeControlStyleStandard];
[[self view] addSubview:likeControl];
```

The problem is that nothing appears on my view inside my app...
Stil the control seems to be well instantiate since the "likeControl.description" gives that in the debug consoled : 
FBLikeControl: 0x1766f6c0; baseClass = UIControl; frame = (20 76; 69 28); layer = CALayer: 0x1763c590>>

ThanX in advance for your help !

David.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.  I could not get like button to show.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495086/fblikecontrol-does-not-load-nor-function

Answer (score 0):

The Like control isn't available for use in production yet - see the notice on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button/

Comment: ThanX for your answer : I'm stuccoed on this issue for 2 days now so I've read the notice a couple of times :-). It says that only the Developpers or Tester of the App will be able to use the control. In my iOS app I use a FB logging associated with the "developper" role in FB App portal : So I expect to be able to use it... Who is able to use this control at the moment ???

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the beta feature for the Like, as follows:

```
[FBSettings enableBetaFeature:FBBetaFeaturesLikeButton];
[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility:NO];
```

All credit goes to [Mawoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495086/fblikecontrol-does-not-load-nor-function)

Usage example:

```
[FBSettings enableBetaFeature:FBBetaFeaturesLikeButton];
[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility:NO];

FBLikeControl *like = [[FBLikeControl alloc] init];
like.frame = CGRectMake(itemX, itemY, 60, 20);
like.likeControlStyle = FBLikeControlStyleButton;
like.objectID = @"http://shareitexampleapp.parseapp.com/photo1/";
```

For some reason I'm not being able to set the 'size' of the like button, also changing the value of the likeControlStyle is not yielding any results, could be because its still a preview feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
FBLikeControl *fblike = [[FBLikeControl alloc] init];
likeControl setLikeControlStyle:FBLikeControlStyleStandard;
    fblike.objectID = @"your facebook link";
    [self.view addSubview:fblike];
```