# FBLikeControl not showing like button

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have been searching for solution for this like button for 2 days now.

I implement Facebook Like button as is written in Facebook developer documents. But like button just won't show on my view?

Has anyone faced similar problem? It also not showing errors. So everything cool just like button is not appearing as it should.

I am creating my like button like this:

```
 FBLikeControl *like = [[FBLikeControl alloc] init];
 like.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 60, 20);
 like.likeControlStyle = FBLikeControlStyleButton;
 like.objectID = @"Facebook link";
 [self.view addSubview:like];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version Facebook iOS SDK are you using. The FB Like button is out of beta only with v3.19. Earlier than that you could only get it show up like explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495086/fblikecontrol-does-not-load-nor-function).

Comment: hvala stari.. deluje!